# Bash vs. Perl Syntax differences

Tags: linux

What are the major syntax differences between bash and perl?  I am new to this and would like to have more of a clear comparison of the two.

Comment: There are far, far more differences than there are similarities, making this question so broad as to make a canonical answer impossible. The answer given by @choroba is a good one, but that's about traps or pitfalls, not attempting to be a canonical list of differences.

Comment: Pretty much the same thing as the syntactic and semantic differences between, say, Swahili and Mandarin... They're two completely different languages. Granted, there is a non-trivial subset of common tasks that can be accomplished in either, and there is some crossover in things like keywords and some other minor notational tricks, but that doesn't necessarily indicate that the languages are similar...

Answer (score 2):

See the "Shell traps" section in [perltrap](http://p3rl.org/perltrap).

> - The backtick operator does variable interpolation without regard to the presence of single quotes in the command.
> - The backtick operator does no
>     translation of the return value, unlike csh.
> - Shells (especially csh)
>     do several levels of substitution on each command line. Perl does
>     substitution in only certain constructs such as double quotes,
>     backticks, angle brackets, and search patterns.
> - Shells interpret
>     scripts a little bit at a time. Perl compiles the entire program
>     before executing it (except for `BEGIN` blocks, which execute at compile
>     time).
> - The arguments are available via `@ARGV`, not `$1`, `$2`, etc.
> - The
>     environment is not automatically made available as separate scalar
>     variables.
> - The shell's test uses `=`, `!=`, `<` etc for string
>     comparisons and `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt` etc for numeric comparisons. This
>     is the reverse of Perl, which uses `eq` , `ne` , `lt` for string
>     comparisons, and `==` , `!=`, `<` etc for numeric comparisons.